# i could'nt connect to mongodb anymore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

in the first try i could connect to my mongodb account at it worked correctly but after 24h hours i couldnt connect anymore at it show me this problem :

>

```
 npm run start

> devconnector@1.0.0 start C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\devconnector
> node server.js

Server running on port 5000
MongoTimeoutError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\devconnector\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:897:9)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  name: 'MongoTimeoutError',
  reason: MongoNetworkError: connection 79 to cluster0-shard-00-00-15tsv.mongodb.net:27017
closed
      at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\devconnector\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connection.js:356:9)
      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:300:26)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at net.js:659:12
      at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:481:7) {
    name: 'MongoNetworkError',
    errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
    [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

this is my keys.js file :  module.exports = {
        mongoURI : "mongodb+srv://jassem:<*******>@cluster0-15tsv.mongodb.net/test",

```
} ; 

and this my code to connect to my Mongodb account : 

//Connect To mongoDB

 mongoose

    const express = require ('express') ;  const mongoose = require ('mongoose') ; 

    .connect(db, {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }) .then(()=> console.log('MongoDB connected')) .catch(err => console.log(err)) ;
```

Comment: did you have to authorize your ip 24hrs ago? it could have changed.

Comment: no it's the same IP .. but i think the problem caused by "MongoTimeoutError"

Comment: have you tried removing `useUnifiedTopology: true` from connection options?

Comment: some result, by the way it worked good yesterday, but today i cannot log in to my mongodb.. i didnt change any code, and i'm sure that my code is correct :/

Comment: Please edit so the code is formatted as code, not a block quote.